# Type 'Firebase' is not assignable to type 'null'. TS2322

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm following along with this tutorial: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial

And I'm at the step where we at the Firebase Context provider with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from './components/App';
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I wanted to do this in typescript just to build my chops and on the `value={new Firebase()}` I'm getting the error `Type 'Firebase' is not assignable to type 'null'.  TS2322`

I'm exactly sure how to edit the value data type assignment as it appears to be set by React itself?

[image: Screenshot of value data type in VSCode]

This is the code for the context provider:

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

Comment: What value you have set in firebaseContext?

Comment: @farooq I guess I don't know enough about React/Typescript to know how to set that value?

Comment: Inside  `src/components/Firebase/context.js` , What is there ? Can you modify your question with code?

Comment: @farooq just added it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

inside your firebase context you need to set the type, you should be able to use `any` for now until you figure out the specific type Firebase returns.

```
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext<any|null>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! 

So the < > allow you to set the value data types? I didn't know that. I'll have to dig into the TS handbook for that explanation. 

Thanks!